# Bind function to elements that are not on DOM when page loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code is here.

```
/*Other code irrelevant*/
<div class="form-group col-lg-1"> 
     <input type="button" class="btn btn-default update"  value="Update">
</div> 

/*Other code irrelevant*/
<div class="form-group col-lg-1"> 
     <input type="button" class="btn btn-default update"  value="Update">
</div>
```

In the js file, I have this:

```
$('.update').click(function() {
    alert("it work");
});
```

However, when I click the update button, only the first update button will respond, the rest will not.

**Important: only the first update button is on html file when page loaded, the rest update buttons are added after I click add button on the page.**

So I want every update buttons, including the ones that are not on the DOM when pages loaded, work as I expected, in this case, just give me an alert message.

Thanks.

Comment: It is working properly, you'd have some other issue in script !

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/sRQ9x/

Comment: Works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/45FNF/ - **Do you have your click event handler inside of your `document.ready` event?** It should be wrapped inside `$(function() { ... });`

Comment: If you add another button to the DOM as you mentioned, you have to add the click event to that new button too.

Comment: the rest update buttons are added after I click add button on the page - It seems like you are adding the buttons dynamically right?

Comment: @jp310 Yes, in this case, how could I still make things work as I expected?

Comment: When you add the button, give it a click event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind events to elements that don't exist at the time you do the binding, you can use [event delegation and the `.on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/). The basic idea is to bind the event to some parent element of the element you're concerned with:

```
$('body').on('click', '.update', function(e) {
  alert("it work")
});
```

What this does is bind the `click` event handler to `<body>`, filtering it so only events that bubbled up from descendants having class `update` will trigger it.

Comment: +1 because you explained what the syntax was and why it would work. Nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.update', function(e){alert("it work")});
```

The issue is that `$(selector).click(handler)` is set when the page is loaded, then if you add other elements with the same selector then jquery does not take into account the new elements.

To fix it you can set the handler to a parent (static) element then each time event is called then parent receive the handler and allows to execute the handler in the child (dynamic) element.

Comment: Maybe you should explain why that works so that the OP can understand and use the technique appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: actually `.each()` Will not work on a dynamic DOM, I did not read the question correctly. You definitely want to use a `.on()` selector as shown by other users. This will dynamically fetch the DOM of the BODY of your page on each click (accounting for anything added to the BODY). You can see it in action with this code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.update', function(e) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        alert( 'We just clicked button with value: ' + value );    
});

$('#add').click(function(){

    var appendage = '<br />/*Other code irrelevant*/<br /><div class="form-group col-lg-1"><input type="button" class="btn btn-default update" value="Update X"></div><br />';
    $('.col-lg-1').append(appendage);

});
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/55xTh/2/)**